# C++ WinRT - does XAudio2 support Xbox One platform?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, xbox, xbox-one, xaudio2

Does XAudio2 support Xbox One? The link below mentions it is for desktop applications only.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/xaudio2/how-to--load-audio-data-files-in-xaudio2

If not supported, what UWP Audio API is available for Xbox One?

Answer (score 1):

XAudio2 is supported for [UWP on Xbox One](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/) as well as for UWP generally.

> That doc note just refers to the utility code in the sample, not the XAudio2 API. The blurb is actually a little out of date because most of those Win32 functions are actually supported in UWP apps with the more recent SDKs. The use of `CreateFile` instead of `CreateFile2` is really the only difference--`CreateFile2` isn't supported by Windows 7.

Comment: thx, I have tested it on Xbox One, XAudio2 does work perfectly.